# Databind to owners datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have 2 forms. The second form is created after pressing a button within the first form. However, the content of the second form is databound to a listbox of items from the first form. I have achieved this so far by setting the datacontext of the second form when creating it through the first form like so:

```
        MainWindow m = new MainWindow
        {               
            DataContext = this.DataContext,
            Owner = this,                
        };
```

The datacontext of the first form is of the selected item of the listbox (which contains items from an entity database. So far this code works fine, I can successfully databind, however as soon as I select another item from the listbox, nothing updates like it should. I guess this is because the datacontext is being set to the item selected when the form was created and it's not databound itself to the datacontext of the first form.

XAML FOR FIRST FORM

```
 DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBoxProperties}"
```

SAMPLE XAML FOR SECOND FORM

```
 <Label Content="{Binding AuctioneerName, Mode=OneWay}"...>
```

I hope I am making sense. How can I databind the datacontext of the second form (either in xaml or c#) so that the selection changes in the first form are recognised in the second one?

Comment: What is it that you call "form"? Is a window?

Comment: yes sorry. form = window

Comment: Maybe it would be easier creating a DataContextChanged event handler for the first window and in this event I could respecify the datacontext for my second window? But can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using DataContextChanged along with searching for any instances of the second window. Once it found the window, the application respecified the datacontext and this is working fine.